# Multi query in mysql using PREPARE... FROM

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I've to run this code in MySQL Workbench:

```
set @myquery = "DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'asd';DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'pol'"
if (@myquery <> '') THEN
    PREPARE st FROM @myquery;
    EXECUTE st;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
END IF;
```

When I run this piece from my SP, it give me a error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'pol'' at line 1
```

But if I execute handly this command it works:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'asd';DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'pol'
```

If I change the query so, it works:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE camp = 'asd';
```

Can you help me?

Comment: AFAIK `IF .. THEN` in MySQL is only allowed in the context of a stored procedure or function.

Comment: and why run two queries for this? why not a single `delete ... where camp in ('asd', 'pol');`?

Comment: Oh, I don't know why, but I haven't thought at this option. Thanks! But why there is the limit if I want to make like my question?

Comment: Also note the following: `SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ";" characters).`. See [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).